# How to detect click events on video (HTML5 video tag)?

Tags: android, android-webview, html5-video

There is a page loaded into Android `WebView` that contains `<video>` tag which obviously loads a remote video. As it happened in the past, this tag causes videos to work on some devices, and on others they do not work - people do not see videos.

I have tried to detect when a user clicks on video so that I can handle video playback outside of the `webview`.

However, when the page loads I DO fetch URL via `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` method and I can handle this part. However, this does not look nice as when you use the app the page will load and when it comes to the video, my code automatically takes over the playback. I would like my code be activated when a users click on play/stop buttons.

Even when I take over the video after page load, and a user goes back to the `webview`, I can NO LONGER detect action on play/stop buttons.

I have overriden all listeners of the `webview` and neither of then catches play/stop button events.

Am I missing something? How shall I detect when a user clicks on play/stop buttons?

Comment: Is this a local video? Or a Youtube video?

Comment: @Steven Neither local or YouTube. A video streamed form the remote server. And it is automatically loaded into player chosen by Android when it sees video tag.